# Swift extension type constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, extension-methods

XCode 11.2.1
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

So, I'm trying to add the ability to remove objects from an array, if I've kept the reference.  Following internet advice, I've caused my protocol to inherit from `AnyObject`, as this causes/requires/implies `===` to be defined on any classes that implement the protocol.  However, XCode is behaving strangely with the types on the Array extension.  Consider that the following compiles fine:

```
public protocol Foo: AnyObject {
}

public extension Array where Element == Foo {
    mutating func removeElement(element: Element) {
        if let idx = self.firstIndex(where: {$0 === element}) {
            self.remove(at: idx)
        }
    }
}

public func bar(array: [Foo], element: Foo) -> [Foo] {
    var arrayCopy: [Foo] = array
    arrayCopy.removeElement(element: element)
    return arrayCopy
}
```

but that if I change the extension type to `Element: AnyObject`, I get a compile error as follows:

```
...
public extension Array where Element: AnyObject {
...
...
    // Compiler error: '[Foo]' requires that 'Foo' conform to 'AnyObject'
    arrayCopy.removeElement(element: element)
...
```

`Foo` DOES conform to `AnyObject`.  It's right there in its definition.  Why does XCode not acknowledge this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using old software so you don't get the modern error message:

> Referencing instance method 'removeElement(element:)' on 'Array'
>   requires that 'Foo' be a class type

And that's true. `element` isn't an instance of a static type, as far as the compiler understands, but it will be if you write it like this instead:

```swift
public func bar<Foo: Module.Foo>(array: [Foo], element: Foo) -> [Foo] {
```

*where `Module` is the actual name of your module, of course.*

---

If you need to use a heterogeneous array, then I don't know how to make things any cleaner than this. Let me know if you figure out better.

(Keep the signature of the function the same; change the body instead.)

```swift
var arrayCopy: [AnyObject] = array
arrayCopy.removeElement(element: element)
return arrayCopy as! [Foo]
```

Comment: Hmm.  This *kindof* works, except that effectively you're replacing `Foo` with `T: Foo`.  This would be fine - except then at the invocation (like `bar([Foo](),FooClass() as Foo)`) Swift tells me "Protocol type 'Foo' cannot conform to 'Foo' because only concrete types can conform to protocols".  The problem has only been pushed elsewhere.  Unless it's just that my software is old?  Would the new `bar` accept an array of `Foo` with newer software?

Comment: I added a "solution" for heterogeneous collections, if that's what you need to work with. ‍♂️

Comment: Sadly, the new solution fails to compile, with the `removeElement` line giving the compiler error "'AnyObject' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'Foo' because 'Foo' has static requirements".  Does it compile in your XCode?  Perhaps it's again a version difference?

Comment: “Works on my machine”! I can’t get that error to show up. Make sure you didn’t accidentally use both parts of what’s above.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, on the assumption that it works as written, I'll accept your answer, and maybe come back to this if I ever update XCode, haha.  Thanks